# Testing sum of dummy variables

Tags: regression, inference, causality, categorical-encoding

Say that you had data for the point spread of a basketball game: Team A points - Team B points (where team A is the home team and team B the away, if there is no home and away team, then team A is randomly allocated).

You run the regression $spread=\beta_1 home + \beta_2 away + \beta_3 neither$

i.e. regress the point spread on three dummy variables and no intercept.

When conducting inference it is obvious that $\beta_3$ should be statistically indifferent from zero because of random allocation to team A and team B (the sign of the point spread). However, im wondering if a necessary restriction to test in this model would be $\beta_1 + \beta_2 = 0$ because a home team achieving some point spread means the away team losing out.

I feel like i am misinterpreting the model by imposing this restriction but i am struggling to convince myself why this is. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what exactly are the "home", "away", and "neither" variables?